# Filewriter Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, filewriter

I have a executor  service  which processes results and writes to a  file  .In short the file will be  written by multiple child  threads , the issue is  when the  first child thread is finished the file writers  is  closed and when the second child thread writes to the file it throws the  below  error :

16:56:06,026 [pool-1-thread-3     ] ExpectedPaymentReportGenerator - Error processing query java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:45)

How to make sure filewriter is open till all the **Child threads**  are finished execution

Comment: This seems like a bad design - how would you stop the threads overwriting each others data ? Why not have all the data in memory from all the threads having run and then write to file ?

Comment: Something you're not telling us about is closing the stream.  The answer is just "don't do that"